# InvalidArgumentError when testing a trained autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, autoencoder

I am trying to implement a conditional autoencoder for asset management purposes. This is the implemented CAE:

```
input_beta = Input((n_tickers, n_characteristics), name='input_beta')
input_factor = Input((n_tickers,), name='input_factor')
hidden_layer = Dense(units=8, activation='relu', name='hidden_layer')(input_beta)
batch_norm = BatchNormalization(name='batch_norm')(hidden_layer)
output_beta = Dense(units=n_factors, name='output_beta')(batch_norm)
output_factor = Dense(units=n_factors, name='output_factor')(input_factor)
output = Dot(axes=(2,1), name='output_layer')([output_beta, output_factor])
model = Model(inputs=[input_beta, input_factor], outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

Follows the training part:

```
model.fit([X1_train, X2_train], X2_train,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=100, initial_epoch=1,verbose=0, shuffle=True)
```

Everything ok till now. When trying to test:

```
pred = model.predict([X1_test,X2_test])
```

gives:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Node: 'model_1/output_factor/BiasAdd'
Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,5000], In[1]: [23000,2]
```

It seems like it is expecting the testing size to be the same as the training size. If I test with the training data, it executes ok:

```
pred = model.predict([X1_train,X2_train])
```

Even though, I would expect that input should require two input, as defined in the model:

```
pred = model.predict([X1_train,X2_train], X2_train)
```